# Como puedo colocarle un tiempo a mi Acces token de cognito?

Tags: reactjs, aws, jwt, cognito

Estoy usando AWS cognito, y quiero que mi access token tenga un tiempo de vida y si no se usa en ese tiempo de vida me saque de la sesión y que si se cierra en el navegador tambien expire el token, para este caso me gustaria guardar mi token en sessión memory, pero no se bien como se hace o que puedo hacer.

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    mandatorySignIn: true,
    region: config.cognito.REGION,
    userPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
    identityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID,
    cookieStorage: {
       domain: process.env.REACT_APP_DOMINION,
       sameSite: 'strict',
       path: process.env.REACT_APP_PATH,
       secure: process.env.REACT_APP_DOMINION !== 'localhost'
    },
    oauth: oauth
  }
})
```

No se si se puede hacer algo similar a esto, pero usando session storage, es posible?

Comment: Hasta donde se, el access token siempre va a tener un tiempo de vida. Pero ese tiempo de vida no depende de que uses dicho token o no. Lo que si que podría hacerse es refrescar el token cuando está próximo a caducar. De esta forma podrías crear tokens que caducasen a los pocos minutos e ir generando nuevos tokens sobre la marcha para extender el tiempo de sesión, algo que únicamente sucedería si el usuario sigue activo. Esto tendrías que programarlo en Amplify

Comment: Si estoy usando el Acces token, pero este al llegar a caducar se vuelve a refrescar y eso es lo que no quiero, quiero que si se caduca yo no lo vuelva a refrescar y me saque del sistema, pero no he logrado hacerlo, alguna idea o configuración del Amplify.config que pueda aplicar para este caso?